# Query a CRM SavedQuery via SQL SSMS

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

In SSMS I can go to our CRM database and run these:

```
SELECT *
FROM SavedQueryBase
WHERE [name] LIKE 'customer%';

SELECT * 
FROM SavedQuery
WHERE [name] LIKE 'customer%';
```

Which both return information on the CRM View.

My Question is - is it possible to actually execute the view in SSMS? In CRM I get 4,000+ records in the View and I need to see these same records in SSMS.  I can't seem to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... found it, but posting it here for the next poor person who also can't figure it out.

You need to look at the FetchXML field which comes back as a result of the queries I posted in the Question.

Then you need to decipher those to build your query. All the info is in the XML, the base table, the fields selected, ordering etc ... Just takes some effort, and of course if the user changes the view, you'll need to redo it.